# Does anyone know of a library which abstracts out the differences between payment gateways?

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, realex-payments-api

I'd like one that covers at least Realex and PayPal, but if it covered others too, that would be wonderful.

Comment: I integrated for DataCash, Paymentech and Paypal and we've been meaning to open source it for quite some time now. But, otherwise -- sorry, I don't know :)

Comment: @typeoneerror. I've forgotten how do do that. Or has it been changed so a moderator has to do it these days?

Comment: Ah, yes. Mods only. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72908/how-to-create-community-wiki-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AktiveMerchant](https://github.com/akDeveloper/Aktive-Merchant) seems to fit the bill